# lit componen event dispact in vue not working

Tags: vue.js, events, lit

am trying to made web component with Lit, so that component can be consume on vanila js, react, angular and vue
So I created component with Lit like code below

```
    import { html, LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";

@customElement("button-ripple")
export class ButtonRipple extends LitElement {
  handleClick(event: Event): void {
    console.log("handleClick from lit is running");

    let customEvent = new CustomEvent("onClickRippleButton", {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
      detail: { value: "hello response from lit" },
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click=${this.handleClick}>
        <slot></slot>
        )}
      </button>
    `;
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "button-ripple": ButtonRipple;
  }
}
```

I tried to run in vanilajs, angular, react with their own way, and it running well as expected
but not in vue

here my vue code

```
<script>
import 'component_from_lit_is_importedhere;
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      btnName:'Cekidot gan'
    };
  },
  methods: {

    onHanleClick(e){
      console.log("onHanleClick = ", e)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button-ripple @onClickRippleButton="onHandleClick($event)">{{btnName}}</button-ripple>
</template>
```

when I try put props "onClickRippleButton" it run console.log that I have set in lit element

but function "onHandleClick" in vue not running at all, and cannot receive argument that I've from Lit Component

is there any way in vue to get parameter that I set in Lit element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Avoiding Verb Prefixes in Event Names**: It's recommended not to use verb prefixes like "on" in event names for custom events. Most modern frameworks handle event binding implicitly, so you don't need to explicitly use "on" when defining event handlers. For example, in Angular, you can simply use `(close)="handle()`, and in Preact, you can use onClose={this.handle}

**Vue Declarative Event Bindings**: Vue allows you to listen to native DOM events dispatched from Custom Elements. However, when using declarative event bindings, Vue only supports lowercase and kebab case event names. If you want to listen for events with different cases, you'll need to write imperative code.

Rename `onClickRippleButton` to `clickRippleButton` something like and try

```
handleClick(event: Event): void {
    console.log("handleClick from lit is running");

    let customEvent = new CustomEvent("clickRippleButton", {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
      detail: { value: "hello response from lit" },
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
  }
```

**References**

[**Reusable UI Component API Guide**](https://github.com/coryrylan/reusable-ui-component-api-guide#custom-events)

**[Custom Elements Everywhere](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/#vue)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the article
actually I did tried your approch by changing name event, but didnt work
actually if we use native event vue its working, but wasn't that anti pattern

Comment: yes it is antipattern if possible could u share example repo?

Comment: yeah sure, please here is the example https://codesandbox.io/s/vuelit-58qjq5
strangely it works in here

Comment: Can you rename web component internal handleClick method to something else and check?

Comment: I did, I tried rename componentnam into camel and kebabcase, also for function name both in vue and lit, may be there is some additional config when lit component publish as package, that is something I need to figure out

Comment: Have you checked lit doc :https://lit.dev/docs/tools/publishing/ ? If you share reproducible example I'll do my best to assist you further

Comment: yes I did, actualy I copy and paste that code
. Also my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/vuelit-58qjq5?file=/src/App.vue:252-260 is using my published npm, 
here is my npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mantulit/v/0.0.5
and the code exactly same
when I running in local computer doesnt work, but work in codesandbox

Comment: I dont know if its okay share link gdrive here, but this is my lit element https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9o-FjnAYkrXwrQtmphu0anXU-wP5k58/view?usp=sharing
pretty simple and basic
should be just npm install && npm run dev

Comment: Hmmm, I always npm run build before using it or publish, but havent try using directly from dist folder, I will try, thx for review